# how to specify appium to one device only

Tags: java, android, automation, adb, appium

I am automating an android device, my target is to automate everything and keep physical maintenance to a minimum. I have two devices with USB debugging on but, when I turn the appium server on it starts running code on the wrong device.

Is there a way to programatically specify which device appium sends code to?

Or is there a way to disconnect a specific adb device through command prompt?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is the last step in finishing my project. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `udid` capability for that.

```
caps.setCapability("udid", "udidDevice");
```

You can find `udidDevice` using `adb devices` command on the terminal with both devices connected and get the one you are interested in.

Comment: how do you find the udid?

Comment: write 'adb devices' on terminal and it will give you the list of the terminals connected to your computer and their udid

Comment: mmm, no. It's a general capability: http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/